# MSAD user cannot access OBIEE 11.1.1.7 analytics home page

Tags: active-directory, obiee

After configuring a MSAD user and setting them up in both OBIEE EM and Console, I could not access OBIEE with said user even if he also had administration privileges.

Comment: Do you have an error message, log file message, anything that might give a clue as to where to start looking?

Comment: I am new to OBIEE, I have OBIEE 11.1.1.7, I configured it with MSAD, users appeared in the console, after I discoved the bug in 11.1.1.7, I stated only virtualied=true, users can be added to application roles in the fusion enterprise manager. after all I expected to login with ad users but I couldn't. I don't know which log file I have to see and report it.

Comment: You can check the sawlog located in the OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent of your installation of OBIEE. That log will tell you why authentication failed, which may shed more light on the underlying problem. Enterprise Manager also keeps a record of the event too, and what log file it is recorded in (which is helpful), but it is easier to read the actual log file. Enterprise Manager does store a unique ECID to each incident, making it easy to track the error/notification. So be sure to look at both the log file and Enterprise Manager.